# binding a partially applied function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, partial-application

I'm a Haskell newbie, so please excuse me if you find this question trivial:

How would I get GHCi to accept a declaration of this sort: `let foo = fmap (*3) . fmap (+10)`?

I tried adding a type declaration to foo (`let foo :: [Int] -> [Int] =` etc) to make the functor type explicit but the compiler responds `Illegal Signature`.

Thanks!

EDIT - Apparently there are quite a few ways to do this. I picked Tikhon's answer because his was among the first, and also fairly intuitive. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: `let foo :: [Int] -> [Int]; foo = {- ... -}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can give the expression (that is, `fmap (* 3) . fmap (+ 10)`) a signature rather than giving it to `foo`. So:

```
let foo = fmap (* 3) . fmap (+ 10) :: [Int] -> [Int]
```

Answer (score 9):

To give type signatures in ghci, the best way, not requiring any extensions, is to separate the signature and the binding with a semicolon,

```
let foo :: Num n => [n] -> [n]; foo = map (*3) . map (+ 10)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer!  I've never thought of using the semicolon like that in ghci.

Answer (score 3):

The full error reads

```
Illegal signature in pattern: [Int] -> [Int]
    Use -XScopedTypeVariables to permit it
```

The solution is to run

```
:set -XScopedTypeVariables
```

Now you can try running your `let foo :: [Int] -> [Int] = fmap (*3) . fmap (+10)` and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
```